# Использование Bootstrap и Vue.js

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js, frontend

Подскажите пожалуйста новичку, как лучше организовать работу с Boostrap и Vue.js:

1. Устанавливать по отдельности
2. Использовать библиотеку Bootstrap + Vue https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/

У меня уже созданы пару компонентов на Vue.js. Хотелось бы использовать и Bootstrap, но нужно понять, не сломает ли все, то что я уже создала. Как-то так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если использовать bootstrap-vue то легче использовать всякие компоненты, проще передавать им параметры, события. Если будет верстальщик в проекте то ему будет проще с обычным бутстрапом. Все пакеты лучше устанавливать через yarn / npm

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

или через npm

```
npm install vue
npm install bootstrap
```

конфликтов быть не должно...